# Are users delinked after from AoG action after a time period?

Tags: actions-on-google

We have account linking turned on our action.

Looking to understand if a user does not use the action for a period of time say 30 days will they be automatically delinked/deregistered from action forcing them to delink?

We issue a refresh token that does not expire so there should be no expiry at least from our iDP provider.

Answer (score 1):

No, even when a user doesn't use the action for like 30 days, Google will not automatically undo the account linking for the user.